# Set Image Name and Positions Programmatically

Tags: android

Before I have hardcoded the positions of Image view and name but now I am retrieving it from the parser

I have ArrayList of the  Positions i.e. X , y and Image name which I retrieved from the xml. Now I want to assign it to my main3.xml layout which has Relative Layout and child as no of  ImageViews of which I have assign positions and this name.

Do I need to inflate the layout or any other idea ? or I should make 10 image views programatically

here is my main3.xml layout this is the hardcoded one now I want to give those topmargin_left and top via code..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/Level1Layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="objectClick" 
            android:background="@drawable/hh_gmw_03">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="593dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="998dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image1"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l01"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image1"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l02" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="497dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image3"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l03" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="524dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="998dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image4"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l04" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="183dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="715dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image5"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l05" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="413dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="557dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image6"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l06" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="532dp" 
        android:onClick="objectClick" 
        android:contentDescription="Image1"
        android:tag="Image7"
        android:src="@drawable/hht3l07" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still may continue using your main3.xml layout and set the margins programmatically:

1. Find identifier for each `ImageView` with [`Resources.getIdentifier(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method, where "name" argument would be generated within some loop as `"imageView" + i`.
2. Set the layout parameters for each `ImageView` with [`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.setMargins(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
3. Call [`View.invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) on the parent of the ImageViews, in your case it's `RelativeLayout` with Level1Layout id.